# How do I show more sentence of my blog post before the read more link in my home page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, genesis

Currently, my site only displays the featured image and the first line of the blog post before the read more bottom, but I want it to display about 4-5 lines.

How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the More Tag in your posts is quite simple. Simply start by writing a new post or edit an existing one.
Once you’re done writing, you will need to click on a line where you would like to end the summary and show a read more link. Next, click on the More Tag button from the toolbar.
You will notice that a dashed line with ‘More’ in the center will appear in your blog post. You can insert the more tag anywhere in the post, like in the mid sentence, in the middle of a paragraph, or after the first paragraph. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your theme use `the_excerpt` you should increase the number of words.
Please the following code in your `functions.php` and change the number, depending how many works you would like to be shown.

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'change_excerpt_length', 999 );
function change_excerpt_length() {
    return 55;
}
```